# What does the message "Adding *k swap on ...' mean?

Tags: linux, kernel, swap

I have the following message in the syslog on some machines:

```
Adding 8385920k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-112957 extents:1 across:8385920k
```

What does it mean? Is it a problem? And why does this message appear in the syslog, as for the moment the machines are not used?

Answer (score 3):

It means your system has an 8GB swap partition. It's not a problem.

Comment: OK, but why is this message repeating every minute in the syslog?

Comment: You must have some cron job, script, or program that's adding and removing swap partitions every minute.

Comment: No. I checked, but there is no cron doing such a thing...

Comment: @francois I suggest you add to your question this information: `this message repeating every minute`